# What files to archive/zip while uploading a phonegap ios app to AppStore via Application Loader?

Tags: ios, cordova

I see two files **my-app.dSYM** and **libCordova.a** and a folder **include**,  along with my app in **Release-iphoneos** folder. Should i archive the app only?
 or should i include others as well?
 I thought the .app file would include the phonegap **libCordova.a** but i didn't find it inside the package contents, so i am confused?
 I am using cordova-2.2.0.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: any reason you're not using Xcode's archive feature? this does everything for you regarding zipping etc.

Comment: thanks for replying, i did try Xcode's archive feature and submitted the app's binary and got the error **invalid binary** as my app's status. i found that the xcode's archive feature  only submits the .app file excluding phonegap libraries and files. so i am guessing that my app's binary was incomplete as it didn't include **libCordova.a**.

Comment: if you've set things up right, archive automatically includes everything. Try setting up a new phonegap project from scratch following their instructions.

Comment: yes i have set things right as i read in the documentation of phonegap [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS "http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_ios_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20iOS"), hence i was able to run successfully in an ipad and three other ios devices. the only problem is while uploading to app store.